# Animate growing an arrow following a curve, for glTF

Tags: animation, gltf

I am creating some infographics assets. I created the rising bar but how do i create the growing arrow  as attached in the picture to show increase in sales. Whatever resources i found was related to moving along an curve path. I want my arrow to start at A and grow along the path to B, using a method suitable for export  for glTF.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Note: that won't work as we now know this is for gltf export. But I let the answer here, if useful for any other cases.

---

That can be this kind of geometry node setup:

[image]

Use 'trim end' as input. This is what you can animate.

Trim the end of the curve and transform it to a mesh using a curve circle.

Sample the end point of the curve in order to have its position and tangent.

Set a cone at this position and orient it to the tangent.

Join the curve and the cone.

[image] (Blender 4.0)

Comment: is there anyway i can achieve this using basic animations as geomtery nodes arent supported by gltf exports as I have to use these assets on web.

Comment: @arjunlokesh, no, I don't think so. You should indicate that in your question, as both answers won't fit in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a curve, a plane object and an arrow tip object, give an *Array* and a *Curve* modifier to the plane object (with the curve as *Curve Object*), in the *Array* modifier choose the tip as *Cap End*:

[image]

Now you can keyframe the *Count* value of the curve to make it grow:

[image]